# How to generate sql from Django model definition?

Tags: django-models

My purpose is to generate Django models dynamically.
I use the following code to create a model.

```py
def create_model(
    name, fields=None, app_label="", module="", options=None, admin_opts=None
):
    class Meta:
        # Using type('Meta', ...) gives a dictproxy error during model creation
        pass

    if app_label:
        # app_label must be set using the Meta inner class
        setattr(Meta, "app_label", app_label)

    # Update Meta with any options that were provided
    if options is not None:
        for key, value in options.iteritems():
            setattr(Meta, key, value)

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {"__module__": module, "Meta": Meta}

    # Add in any fields that were provided
    if fields:
        attrs.update(fields)

    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    # Create an Admin class if admin options were provided
    if admin_opts is not None:

        class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            pass

        for key, value in admin_opts:
            setattr(Admin, key, value)
        admin.site.register(model, Admin)
    return model
```

```py
Then I know I need to generate sql from model and synced into database.   
I use the following code:

def install(custom_model):
    from django.core.management import color
    from django.db import connection
    from django.db.backends.base import schema

    style = color.no_style()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    statements, pending = connection.creation.sql_create_model(custom_model, style)
    for sql in statements:
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

However, it told me that
**AttributeError: 'DatabaseCreation' object has no attribute 'sql_create_model'**
My Django version is 2.0 and yes it has no sql_create_model.
My question is how to generate sql from a model with Django 2.0?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution for this

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
    editor.create_model(model)
```

**NOTE** If you have unique_together in Meta, 'with' statement is necessary as deferred_sql is defined in __enter__ method, otherwise you will get exception of no attribute 'deferred_sql'. Please check the django 'BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor' code in backends/base/schema.py

```
class BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor:
    ... ...

    def __enter__(self):
        self.deferred_sql = []
        if self.atomic_migration:
            self.atomic = atomic(self.connection.alias)
            self.atomic.__enter__()
        return self

    ... ...

    def create_model(self, model):
        ... ...

        # Add any unique_togethers (always deferred, as some fields might be
        # created afterwards, like geometry fields with some backends)
        for fields in model._meta.unique_together:
            columns = [model._meta.get_field(field).column for field in fields]
            self.deferred_sql.append(self._create_unique_sql(model, columns))
        ... ...
```

Comment: It appears that this does not work with SQLite

Comment: `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: SQLite schema editor cannot be used while foreign key constraint checks are enabled. Make sure to disable them before entering a transaction.atomic() context because SQLite does not support disabling them in the middle of a multi-statement transaction.`